# Many Many to relationship Query

Tags: junction-object

I have uploaded Object Owner records and Object Contractor records. Also I have a Junction Object OwnerContractorAssociation. I have already established many to many relationship using junction object. But to populate records in Junction Object, I am unable to figure out the way to achieve it. Please guide on how to do it.

Thank you.

Comment: Please wait for answers on your original question Reddy. Asking the same again will only confuse people and fragment relevant responses to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a visual force page and in that page first insert you "Owner's Record" then insert "Contractor's records".

Later on in the junction object insert owner.id "OwnerContractorAssociation.owner"
and "contractor.id" in "OwnerContractorAssociation.contactor" then insert OwnerContractorAssociation.